# Ошибка при запуске программы на Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

В питоне я пока что полный нуб,поэтому запрашиваю помощь
Только начал учится,решил написать простой саундборд с кнопкой.
Используя все свои никчемные скиллы накатал вот это

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

Config.set("graphics", "resizable", "0")
Config.set("graphics", "width", "300")

Config.set("graphics", "height", "300")
class meladzeApp(App):

def playSound(self, som, instance):
song = SoundLoader.load("Sound.mp3")
song.play()
self.playing.append(song)

def build(self):

add_widget(Button(text = 'KPACUBO', on_press = self.song.play()))

meladzeApp().run()
```

Командная Строка выдает ошибку на 15 строке

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас ошибка отступов. Вы инициализируете класс, но его тело пустое.

Скорее всего, Вы имели в виду:

```py
# ...
class meladzeApp(App):
    def playSound(self, som, instance):
        song = SoundLoader.load("Sound.mp3")
        song.play()
        self.playing.append(song)

    def build(self):
        add_widget(Button(text = 'KPACUBO', on_press = self.song.play()))
# ...
```

Comment: Все,теперь вроде понял
Я после каждого двоеточия должен делать Таб-отступ

Comment: @ikerra13 Кстати, для отступов рекомендуется использовать 4 пробела (`PEP-8`).

Comment: Ответ приму,могу только через 4 минуты.
Инфу принял,примного благодарен)